# Scala, Maven, Sbt and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven, sbt

I am wondering what is the most efficient way to use Sbt and Eclipse together? There seems to be a [Sbt Eclipse plugin](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse/) but what is the generally recommended workflow post generating the eclipse config? It seems kind of wrong to then add dependencies via the Eclipse Maven plugin in Eclipse? Is that what people usually do though?

Kind of new to the ecosystem so maybe I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I add maven dependencies in via the sbt config files. Then regenerate the eclipse project after each modification, keeping the sbt config as the definitive project specification. I suspect it's the only sane way to run the setup.

Comment: This is exactly what I do, and it works great. No need for Maven to be involved at all.

Comment: How do you regenerate the Eclipse project?

Answer (score 0):

I use the IvyDE plugin for eclipse with sbt deliver-local.

The advantage here is it can give you separate classpath containers for different configurations easily and you don't need to blat your eclipse project settings regularly.

It'd be really nice if scala-ide supported tighter integration with sbt.